# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a una view en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problemas realice un controlador y especifique  la ruta en mi archivo routes, pero al no se como llamar esa ruta a través de un botón  o un link, si me pueden ayudar, intente ver varios ejemplos pero me arroja error:

> 404 not found

Rutas públicas:

```
Route::get('/crear-cuenta', [RegistrarController::class , 'index'])->name('crearCuenta'); //Mostrar la vista "Crear cuenta"
```

Controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegistrarController extends Controller

{
public function index(){

   return view("registrar");
   
}
```

Vista:

```
 <center><small>¿no tienes cuenta? <a href="{{route('crear-cuenta') }}" id="linkCrear">Crea una</a></small></center>
```

Comment: Deberia ser `route('crearCuenta')` porque le estas llamando `->name('crearCuenta')` como dice la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas el helper route, debes colocar el name que le colocaste a tu ruta, es decir, colocaste: `route('crear-cuenta')` cuando debería ser: `route('crearCuenta')`.

Si quieres hacer uso de la uri, para eso está el otro helper llamado url, y solo debes hacer: `url('crear-cuenta')`, este sí te redirigiría a tu vista.

Para más referencias, acá está información de [route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) y de [url](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url)